# Solution of Bessel's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, mathematical-modeling, bessel-functions

I am trying to solve Bessel's equation ${x^2}{y''}+{x}{y'}+{\left(x^2-v^2\right)}{y}=0$ . When I reached $c_{2n}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^nc_0}{2^{2n} n!\left(1+v\right)\left(2+v\right)\ldots\left(n+v\right)}$ then in zill book it is written that "it is standard practice to choose $c_0$ to be specific value , namely $c_0=\frac{1}{2^v\Gamma\left(1+v\right)}$" my question how $c_0$ is choosen. Elaborate it

Comment: Why the tag "partial-differential-equations" ? I see no PDE in the question. (-1).

Comment: Of course, choosing any value you like for $c_0$ gives you a solution.  But one particular solution has been given a name.  That is the one chosen.  It is called (for historical reasons) the Bessel function $J_v(x)$.

Comment: Re "zill book". Do you mean Dennis G. Zill , *A First Course in Differential Equations*, or some other book?

Comment: Yes Dennis g zill book , where particular value choose , my question how it is choosen,do we choose other values of co